# Apache Velocity + Servlet 3.0

Tags: java, apache, velocity, servlet-3.0

I'm upgrading from servlet 2.5 to 3.0, and I'm using Apache Velocity for templating, after a mvn dependency:tree I see velocity-tools depends on servlet-api:jar:2.3, there's a way to use servlet 3.0 with Apache Velocity?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The servlet API is backward compatible. I would be surprised if velocity didn't work with the servlet 3.0 api.

Comment: I mean Velocity keeps using version 2.3 instead of 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem; my Servlet 3.0 project wouldn't compile because servlet-api 2.3 was on the Maven classpath as a dependency of Velocity Tools.

The work-around is to declare the Velocity dependency as `runtime` so at compile-time the project still builds with Servlet 3.0

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
   <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
   <version>2.0</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maven dependencies don't mean *I need **exactly** this version of the library*, but almost *I need **at least** this version*. This means that if you declare a dependency on version 3.0 of the servlets library, that is the one that's going to be used.

And the 3.0 version of the servlets specification is backwards compatible with the 2.5 version, meaning that whatever Velocity needs from Servlets is going to be available.